# linux compare text file

Tags: files, uniq

I have `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, both contain URLs, I want to create a new file with the unique URLS present in `file2.txt` and not in `file1.txt`.

Example urls file:

```
aspencabinets.com.au
iiatca.org
energyoil.co.za
tevelatino.com
handball-schule.com
lindaestelle.com
latindancegrooves.com
ugurlu-ozturk.com
robertsdoneright.com
pactoconvex.com
ghaudit.org
keiramontalli.net
taksid.ee
katanics.hu
baggotpureescape.com
naechstenliebe.net
wiki.mbremer.de
boxplandesign.com.sg
lhasa.ca
roboticengineeringprojects.com
killergaming.info
nhswga.com
culnue.eu
fmovers.com
corpuschristicarolstream.org
promedmedikal.com
creationprints.com.au
tsukihime.com
```

Comment: Show two example input files, and what output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comm

first sort the files:

```
sort file1 -o file1_sorted
sort file2 -o file2_sorted
```

Of course you can use

```
sort file1 -o file1
```

To sort in-place

then use comm as following:

```
comm -2 3 file2_sorted file1_sorted > newfile
```

[comm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) compares sorted files

Or if your shell supports process substitution (bash, zsh and some kshs):

```
comm -23 <(sort file2) <(sort file1) > newfile
```

- -3: remove the 3rd column (URLs found in both files)
- -2: remove the second column (URLs only found in `file1_sorted`)

That leaves only the first column (URLs only found in `file2_sorted`).

Comment: You can sort the files on the fly: `comm -3 <(sort file2) <(sort file1)`.